# Why is there a <noscript> tag in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and am running a simple application (following tutorial at https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html and modifying code for my own project).

I see a

```
<noscript>
You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
</noscript>
```

in my HTML, not sure if that is breaking something or why it is there.  Any help is appreciated, I can give code samples if necessary but I have no idea where the noscript is coming from

Comment: Do you have JavaScript enabled in your browser?

Comment: Yes I do, I was thinking that the react error I saw in the console were causing react to halt javascript execution but I was wrong.

Comment: Because the React team does not think about accessibility or progressive enhancements.

Answer (score 12):

It's because React is a Javascript Library and according to [w3schools noscript tag definition](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_noscript.asp)

> The content inside the `<noscript>` element will be displayed if scripts
>   are not supported, or are disabled in the user's browser.
>
> The  element can be used in both `<head>` and `<body>`.
>
> When used inside the `<head>` element: `<noscript>` must contain only
>   `<link>`, `<style>`, and `<meta>` elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, the WAVE Web Accessibility Evaluation Tool seems to be flagging this noscript element with a warning.

Answer (score 8):

Anything within `<noscript></noscript>` tags will render only when JavaScript is disabled or the browser doesn't support JavaScript.

**Definition and Usage:**

- The `<noscript>` tag defines an alternate content for users that have disabled scripts in their browser or have a browser that doesn't support script.
- The `<noscript>` element can be used in both `<head>` and `<body>`.
- When used inside the `<head>` element: `<noscript>` must contain only `<link>`, `<style>`, and `<meta>` elements.
- The content inside the `<noscript>` element will be displayed if scripts are not supported, or are disabled in the user's browser.

**Browser Support:**

Every borowser.

**Differences Between HTML 4.01 and HTML5:**

- In HTML 4.01, the `<noscript>` tag can only be used inside the  element.
- In HTML5, the `<noscript>` tag can be used both inside `<head>` and `<body>`.

**Differences Between HTML and XHTML:**

- In XHTML, the `<noscript>` tag is not supported.

Reference: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_noscript.asp)

Comment: What specifically should we looking at under `learn more...`?

Comment: @Popeye For example `Definition and Usage`, `Browser Support` and etc.

Comment: It was more of a suggestion to improve your answer. Links can and do expire. Whilst I don't believe your answer is relying on the link (if it was I would have downvoted) it could potentially improve your answer if you shared the content in the link you are referring too. `Vinicius Zomer`s answer is a good example of what I mean

Comment: @Popeye Thanks for your suggestion. I fixed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

noscript tag is just like a semantic tag which is used to have a clear understanding that when we don't have javascript present in our current environment then what should be displayed in the browser. Whatever is present between the noscript tags will be shown on the screen. And in your case you don't need to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I don't think it was answered, Lets say you have an app that needs navigation and content to a user but can dynamcally load content for those that have javascript.  You can create a server-side react component that would render plain HTML while hydrating the app to give a more rich app experience to those that have javascript.

Answer (score 1):

In case user has disabled the JavaScript in the browser, or it is not supported, then the message inside the tag will be shown.